# Como Deixar Elemento LI 100%

Tags: html, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A foto acima representa um slider que estou fazendo em uma página.

Cada slider tem uma imagem no meio que representa a esfera branca.

Eu quero que todos os sliders que são formados por um `li` sejam do mesmo tamanho, do mesmo tamanho que o maior, isto é, o slider laranja.

Independente da cor, só foi um exemplo, quero que sejam do mesmo tamanho.

A linha preta representa o final do `li` laranja. Quero que todos os outros vão até o final.

Eu tentei...

```
ul{
    height: 100%;
}

li{
    height: 100%;
}
```

...mas não deu certo.

Os `li(s)` não tem nenhum tamanho fixo. Eles apenas ficam com a altura do objeto que está no meio, as vezes o objeto é maior que o outro e acaba dando essa diferença.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`height: 100%`** precisa de uma referência para ser calculada. Considere o exemplo:

```css
 .x {
   height: 100%;
   background: red
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='x'>StackOverflow</div>
</body>
```

Funciona? Sim, funciona.

Talvez não funcione "visualmente" falando, afinal esperava-se que `.x` ocupasse 100% da altura do *body*. Mas se considerar o snippet acima, que tamanho tem o *body*? Uma pergunta simples: Como um elemento vai ocupar 100% de altura de um outro elemento que não possui altura?

Pegando o mesmo snippet acima e atribuindo um valor ao `height` do *body*, eis o resultado:

```css
body {
  height: 300px /* exemplo */
}
.x {
  height: 100%;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='x'>StackOverflow</div>
</body>
```

Talvez aí entre o problema do código que postou, não ficou claro onde essa `ul` e as `li` estão sendo colocadas e se os elementos pais possuem tamanho. Mas basta que você estabeleça uma referência para elas calcularem 100% de altura.

```css
.referencia {
  height: 200px /* a referência tem 200px de altura */
}

ul {
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%
}

li:nth-child(1){ background: #A50D18 }
li:nth-child(2){ background: #636363 }
li:nth-child(3){ background: #003662 }
li:nth-child(4){ background: #F26522 }
```

```html
<div class='referencia'>
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Consegui.

Coloquei no `ul` a propriedade:

`display: table`.

Porquê o `li` já estava `display: inline-block`.